# Enforce TLS 1.2 when uploading files in azure blob storage using Java sdk

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, tls1.2, azure-sdk-for-java

Java SDK for Azure Blob Storage uses NFS but we want to use TLS 1.2 when uploading files using blobclient. Though the minimum setting in account is set as TLS 1.2 but how can client upload files from their application using TLS 1.2 ?

```
BlobServiceClient blobSvcClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
           .endpoint(storageActUrl) // https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/blob.txt
           .sasToken(sasToken)
           .buildClient(); 
BlobClient blobClient = blobSvcClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName).getBlobClient(blobName);
BlobHttpHeaders blobHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders().setContentLanguage("en-US").setContentType("binary");
blobClient.uploadFromFile(filePath, null, headers, null, AccessTier.HOT, new BlobRequestConditions(), Duration.ofMinutes(30));
```

Answer (score 0):

After research, found below code which enforces TLS 1.2. Writing it down in case it helps others.

```
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```